# Compiling MySQL custom engine in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, compiler-construction

I have compilation errors while compiling MySQL sample of storage engine from MySQL 5.1.36 sources.  Looks to me that I set all paths to include subdirectories but that seems not enough.

Here are the errors:

1>c:\users\roman\desktop\mysql-5.1.36\sql\field.h(1455)    : error C2065: 'FRM_VER' : undeclared    identifier

1>c:\users\roman\desktop\mysql-5.1.36\sql\item_cmpfunc.h(1395)    : error C2146: syntax error : missing    ';' before identifier 'preg'

1>c:\users\roman\desktop\mysql-5.1.36\sql\item_cmpfunc.h(1395)    : error C4430: missing type specifier
   - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

1>c:\users\roman\desktop\mysql-5.1.36\sql\item_cmpfunc.h(1395)    : error C4430: missing type specifier
   - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to include mysql_version.h.in library that contain all appropriate variables like FRM_VER, etc.  That resolved the errors metioned above.